# JQuery not null with css not woking

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to apply these `css` in `jquery` when the input field have some value,
I tried these `jquery` codes, but it's not working.

Please suggest me!

```
if ($('#user-email').val() != ''){
    $(".email-capt").css({"position":"absolute","margin-top":"0px"});
}
```

```html
<div class="input-container input-email">
     <button class="btn btn-default email-btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></button>
     <input type="email" required="" value="" tabindex="1" name="name" class="" id="user-email">
     <label for="arrival" class="email-capt">Enter your email to be in the know</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Show us your HTML

Comment: Is this piece of code is working on button click? What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check when your `input` field's value is changing. At the moment, you are checking when the `DOM` loads.

Try this out, instead:

```
$("#user-email").change(function(){ // on input value change  
    if($.trim($(this).val()) != ''){
        $(".email-capt").css({"position":"absolute", "margin-top":"0px"});
    }
});
```

If you want to check when the `button` is clicked, you can do something like this:

```
$(".email-btn").click(function(){ // if button is clicked
    if($.trim($(this).val()) != ''){
        $(".email-capt").css({"position":"absolute", "margin-top":"0px"});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function checkFilled() {
    var inputVal = document.getElementById("subEmail");
    if (inputVal.value == "") {
        inputVal.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }
    else{
        inputVal.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
}

checkFilled();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="subEmail" onchange="checkFilled();">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  if ($('#user-email').val() != ''){
    $(".email-capt").css({"display":"block","color":"red"});
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-container input-email">
     <button class="btn btn-default email-btn">Click</button>
     <input type="email" required tabindex="1" name="name" id="user-email">
     <label for="arrival" class="email-capt" style="display:none;">Enter your email to be in the know</label>
</div>
```

The problem was that, the js code only runs one time when the page is loaded. 

You need to define that onClick of the button the code should run. For that use this -- `$('button').click(function() {...});`